# Get the value from input of Formik's Field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik, yup

There is a Formik field for validating some data, it looks like this:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={values => this.handleDelete(values)}>
    {({ values, errors, touched, setFieldValue }) => (
      <Form>
        <Field
          className="add-input"
          name="deleteText"
          as={Input}
          placeholder="Write DELETE"
        />
      </Form>
    )}
 </Formik>
```

If I write a text, "abc" in the input, with DevTools in Inspect mode this looks like this:

```
<form action ="#">
  <div class="ui input add-input">
     <input name="deleteText" placeholder="Write DELETE" type="text" value="abc">
  </div>
</form>
```

Here it can be seen the introduced text, but how can I access it that text from the code?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `values[<name>]` like `values['deleteText']` for your code (inside the render function of the Formik)

or

2. You can pass `onChange` prop to the `<Field>`